# Separate OSM postgis streetdata that contains data for markers in center of street

Tags: postgresql, geocoding, openstreetmap, postgis, geodjango

I'm kinda new to Django and OSM but after hours of googling I didn't find my answer.
I have set up my own OSM tileserver which runs on a postgis database (psql). The tile server runs fine. Now I want to do the following.

I want to add markers in the center of each street in a specific area. I want add all these markers in the database on forehand, because the data is already there (nodes,lines,way etc.) and I want to give streets additional values. This means that i have to add all the streets to my database. In my head these tables must at least contain:

**Name of street, City, Country, Lon, lat (of the center of the street)**

This way I can call-up the markers and values from the database. Is this the right way of thinking, and how do I get this street data from my postgis db to this new table with the right relations and coordinates?

I hope someone could help me.

Comment: If you want to reach a larger OSM community then try [help.openstreetmap.org](http://help.openstreetmap.org) or [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If someone else encounters the same problem: The question has been asked here, too: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/30763/separate-osm-postgis-streetdata-that-contains-data-for-markers-in-center-of-street